# Does one need an external, peer-reviewed grant to become tenured faculty in this field?

Tags: career

As a secondary question, how important is it to be awarded grants to remain employed as a PhD mathematician at an academic research institution? Is it common or uncommon for PhD mathematicians to have independent grants?

Comment: What is your definition of "tenured faculty" in a country/system that does not have tenure in the North American sense?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that my question pertains to US academic research institutions only.

Comment: There are over 3000 four-year colleges and universities in the US.  It is impossible to make general statements about research/grant expectations for faculty at them.

Answer (score 4):

Many mathematicians have never held a grant (even at my own institution). No mathematician that I know of has been denied tenure (or anything equivalent) on grounds of not obtaining a grant or not obtaining an external grant. It is common in some countries for mathematicians to have grants, for example (I believe) it is common in France and Canada, but it is unheard of in Ireland, where it is forbidden by government policy to award grants to scientific research that does not have immediate industrial or social application.